# The servlet does not show all the match results from joining two tables

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have the field in my JSP `<c:param name="names" value="${tempstudent.name}"/>` for showing the user name and my servlet take this field by `String names=request.getParameter("names")` and send it to the student_db_util  class in the method named `public List <studentrgister> showcourse(String names)` as a parameter  which has a task to take a names and use it in my sql query to show match result from 2 tables(mytest table which has a firstName,lastName, id column and class table which has an id, class column). the problem for this app is that in both tables there is more than one match result when I join both tables but my app only show on match result in my JSP page

```
<body>
<table>
<form action="studentregister" method="get">

                        <input type="hidden" name ="comand" value="seecourse"/> 


<c:forEach var="tempstudent" items="${mycourse}">
                                                <td >${tempstudent.name}</td>
</c:forEach>
</form>
</table>
```

jsp page that names field located

```
<form action="studentregister" method="get">
                        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="pass" />
<table>
<c:forEach var="tempstudent" items="${studentlist}">
<c:url var="seecourse" value="studentregister">
            <c:param name="command" value="seecourse"/>
            <c:param name="names" value="${tempstudent.name}"/>
            </c:url>
                        <td >${tempstudent.email}</td>
                                                <td >${tempstudent.name}</td>
                                                <a href="${seecourse}"
                        >
                        seecourse</a>   

</c:forEach>
</table>
</form>
```

servlet method

```
    private void seecourse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String names=request.getParameter("names");
        student_db_util.showcourse(names);
        List<studentrgister> student=student_db_util.showcourse(names);
        request.setAttribute("mycourse", student);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/showcourse.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request,response);   
    }
```

method in student_db_util class

```
public List <studentrgister> showcourse(String names) throws Exception {
        List<studentrgister> students = new ArrayList<>();
         String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker";
          System.out.println("loding the driver");
          Statement s=null;


        studentrgister mystudent=null;
        Connection myConn = null;
        myConn= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "webstudent", "webstudent"); 
      System.out.println("username and password is correect");

        PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        String  name=names;
try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          System.out.println("driver is loaded");
    //myConn = dataSource.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT mytest.firstName,class.name FROM mytest "
                 + "INNER JOIN class ON mytest.id=class.id "
                 + "where mytest.firstName = ? " ;
                PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1,name); 
    myRs=ps.executeQuery();
    if (myRs.next()) {
        String classname = myRs.getString("name");
        //String numbername=myRs.getString("firstName");
        mystudent = new studentrgister(classname);
        students.add(mystudent);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Could not find student id: " );
        }           




        return students;
}
        finally {
            close(myConn,myStmt,null);

        }

    }
```

Comment: How many results do you get from the query ?

Comment: only one  result

Answer (score 0):

This List declaration is inside the method but the method returns the variable,
i assume the students variable should be outside the method in an accessible scope to be used. You should declare the List globally in the class so it can be accessed outside the method or if you have another students variable outside to return to it cannot return the local scoped variable declared in the method.

```
List<studentrgister> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I define an ArrayList globally but it just repeats the first result more than one time so now I have 2 string on my page but still its not a correct result ( i suppose to have for my user math, java, c#  but I have math, math